# Как найти ячейку с определенным значением в ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, closedxml

Только начал юзать ClosedXML. Сразу столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями.
Задача: Есть документ (Учебная нагрузка). В нем для каждого преподавателя расписана его учебная нагрузка. Пример документа ниже

[image: Here is example]

Мне нужно найти ячейку с заранее мне известным именем преподавателя. Т.е. я знаю, что нужная мне ячейка находится во 2 столбце и имеет значение, к примеру "Большаков Алексей Александрович". Я попытался найти метод, который бы волшебным образом решил эту задачу, но не найдя такого написал свою реализацию, которая естественно не работает. Пробовал еще некоторые варианты, но и они успехом не увенчались. Люди добрые, что я делаю не так? Очень хочу исправиться, помогите.

P.S.: Пример кода

```
IXLCells c = wb.Worksheet(1).Column(1).CellsUsed(x => x.Value.ToString() == "");
foreach (IXLCell x in c)
{
    if(x.Value.ToString() == LoginForm.Activ_User)
    {
        str = LoginForm.Activ_User;
        Success rtr = new Success(str);
        rtr.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык :)

Comment: Перевел. Почему то решил, что на ru кластере тоже следует спрашивать на английском (:

Comment: Может стоит в режиме отладки посмотреть какое значение принимает `x.Value.ToString()`  в искомой ячейке? По результату можно будет уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условие поиска выглядит странно: `x => x.Value.ToString() == ""` означает что будут выбраны только пустые ячейки.

Можно обратить условие, чтобы выбрать непустые:

```
IXLCells c = wb.Worksheet(1).Column(1).CellsUsed(x => x.Value.ToString() != "");
```

Согласно документации, вызов `CellsUsed` без аргумента итак отбирает непустые ячейки, так что можно обойтись без условия:

```
IXLCells c= wb.Worksheet(1).Column(1).CellsUsed();
```

Можно также сразу отобрать ячейки с нужным значением:

```
var userCells = wb.Worksheet(1).Column(1)
            .CellsUsed(x => String.Equals(LoginForm.Activ_User, x.Value.ToString()));
foreach (IXLCell x in userCells)
{
    //отобраны только ячейки значение которых равно LoginForm.Activ_User
    str = LoginForm.Activ_User;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Условие поиска не было пустым изначально. Просто в процессе перебора вариантов заменил пустой строкой, уже не помню даже для чего. В любом случае, как оказалось дело, конкретно в моём случае было в том, что при сравнении значения переменной LoginForm.Activ_User со значением ячейки криво представлялись данные в LoginForm.Activ_User. 
Данный ответ пометил как правильный, т.к. при исправлении всех своих косяков, и использовании Ваших советов все заработало как нужно. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Dragan94 рад, что все заработало, спасибо за принятый ответ! Чтобы в дальнейшем избежать побочных эффектов, вроде ошибки с `LoginForm.Activ_User` нужно создавать для вопроса [самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)